# What is meant by the indefinate pronoun 'one' when used in a statement like 'I dont understand why you'd bother'

Tags: pronouns, third-person, impersonal-passive

You'd is shorthand for you would.
You is the colloquial for one.
So the statement 'I don't understand why you'd bother' is synonymous with the statement 'I don't understand why one would bother'?

One is an English language, gender-neutral, indefinite pronoun that means, roughly, "a person." For purposes of verb agreement it is a third-person singular pronoun. But one can also be used as a pronoun for person of the speaker's kind; such as the speaker himself or herself:

So in the statement 'I don't understand why you'd bother'
is the speaker saying they don't understand why someone like themselves would bother?

Or is the speaker saying they don't understand why a person (someone other than themselves, third person) would bother?

How can the meaning of 'one' be infered from the statement. Or is it simple down to the speaker to decide upon its intended meaning?

Many thanks for adding any clarification to this

Comment: But *I don't understand why **you** would bother* is **not** necessarily synonymous with *I don't understand why **one** would bother*.

Comment: But isn't you just the informal use of one? For example You is usually a second person pronoun. It is also used to refer to an indeterminate person, as a more common alternative to the very formal indefinite pronoun one.[18]

Example: "One should drink water frequently" or "You should drink water frequently". Taken from https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/You

Comment: As you just said in your comment, they each have different senses. It's only when they are being used in the *same* sense that they can be exchanged with each other. If I say, "Jack, you are wrong," that's not the same thing as me saying, "Jack, one is wrong."

Comment: Saying "Jack, one is wrong" to an addressee can be a polite (though very formal), way of saying "Jack, you are wrong".

Answer (score -1):

From [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/one#Pronoun):

*Pronoun*

**one** (reflexive oneself, possessive adjective one’s, plural ones)

3. (indefinite personal pronoun) Any person (applying to people in general).

Also from [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/you#Pronoun):

*Pronoun*

**you** (second person, singular or plural, nominative or objective, possessive determiner your, possessive pronoun yours, singular reflexive yourself, plural reflexive yourselves)

6. (indefinite personal pronoun) Anyone, one; an unspecified individual or group of individuals (as subject or object).

So we can see it's synonymous with **anyone**. As you said, it means people in general, or any person.

Comment: After doing some more reading it seems the _you_ is a generic you https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_you. But how is the listener able to know if the speaker was using it to refer to themselves or an unspecified person. 'I don't own a car. I don't understand why you would' is the speaker declaring they don't understand why any person would own a car, or declaring there there is no need for themselves to own one?